# Same code different syntax(ilm_client.h vs ilm_control_platform.h)

Tags: c++, syntax

I would like to know that in the following code is `(*layerSetOpacity)` is some sort of function pointer. I could not find the reference anywhere in the whole repository!

The following code found in ilm_client.h is understandable as `ilm_layerSetOpacity` pertains to function

```
ilmErrorTypes ilm_layerSetOpacity(t_ilm_layer layerId, t_ilm_float opacity);
```

But this code found in ilm_control_platform.h is confusing as what does bracket with pointer represent - function pointer?

```
 ilmErrorTypes (*layerSetOpacity)(t_ilm_layer layerId,
               t_ilm_float opacity);
```

I am not asking for code specifics only the syntax.

Comment: Yes, function pointer.

Comment: Thanks but how can we find out which function it points to as I checked the whole repository for the function https://github.com/Airtau/genivi/blame/master/layer_management/

Comment: ilm_control_platform.h does not seem to be part of that repository. Is it a generated file?

Comment: https://github.com/GENIVI/wayland-ivi-extension/blob/master/ivi-layermanagement-api/ilmControl/include/ilm_control_platform.h

Comment: This is the main repository . It has both

Comment: it looks to me like the assignment should be happening in `init_ilmControlPlatformTable()`, which is not in that repository either (hence why you can't find it).

Comment: How did you figure that out? because it begins with `init` and has `Table()` Thats pretty smart actually!

Comment: Yeah, your function pointer is member of a struct (which looks like a vtable) instantiated once as a global variable: `gIlmControlPlatformFunc`, so it would make sense that `init_ilmControlPlatformTable()`, decalred on the very next line is meant to initialize that global variable.

Comment: That actually makes lots of sense. I did try searching for `init_ilmControlPlatformTable()` to further understand but it appears its not there in the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's dissect: - `ilmErrorTypes (*layerSetOpacity)(t_ilm_layer layerId, t_ilm_float opacity)`:-

1. `layerSetOpacity` is a pointer to a function that takes 2 params as input
2. The inparams to the function  are of type `t_ilm_layer` and `t_ilm_float`
3. The function returns a adata type `ilmErrorTypes`

The fact that you can't find anything in your code base that matches the symbol `layerSetOpacity` means the function pointer is **declared** in the header but never **invoked** using this function pointer but quite possibly invoked using `ilm_layerSetOpacity`

A simpler analogy would be:-

```
int a = 10;
int *p1; //Uninitialized pointer
int *p2 = &a; //pointer pointing to a
```

In your case `a` is `ilm_layerSetOpacity` and `p1` is `layerSetOpacity` and `p2` does not exist
HTH!

Comment: I see but why is it that in other code the function pointer `layerSetOpacity` is declared as a function `ilm_layerSetOpacity`? Are the two same?

Comment: A function pointer is just a variable that can refer to a function with a matching signature. It plays no role in declaring/defining functions.

Comment: There is no relation between `ilm_layerSetOpacity` and `layerSetOpacity`